# Area of triangle inside a $30-60-90$ triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> In a right angle triangle ABC with hypotenuse BC and C=60 degrees, M and N are the middles of AB and AC respectively. Draw ND perpendicular to BC (D is point on the side BC). If MD=7cm calculate the area of triangle DNM.

[image]

I solved this question in the following way:

$NM//=\frac{CB}{2}$ (Thales theorem)

ABC=30 degrees hence $CA=\frac{CB}{2}$ and hene $NM=CA$

$sinNCD=\frac{ND}{CN}$

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}*CN=ND$

$CN=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}*ND$

$AC=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}*ND$

$MN=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}*ND$

since NM//CB then DNM=90 degrees.

Hence, $DN^2+DN^2*\frac{16}{9}=49$ (Pythagoras), so $DN^2*\frac{25}{9}=49$, so $DN*\frac{5}{3}=7$, so $DN=\frac{21}{5}$

From this we have that $MN=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}*\frac{21}{5}=\frac{84}{5\sqrt{3}}$.

Hence $Area=\frac{MN*ND}{2}=\frac{42}{5\sqrt{3}}*\frac{21}{5}=\frac{21*42}{25\sqrt{3}}=\frac{882}{25\sqrt{3}}$

Could you please tell me if I am correct and if I am wrong how much would it be reasonable to assume I would get in an olympiad for my work?

Comment: You could have suspected that your result was too big. If you multiply num and den by $\sqrt 3$ you get $\frac{294 \sqrt{3}}{25}\approx 20$ (without calculator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a mistake here

$$ DN^2+DN^2*\frac{16}{\color{red}{3}}=49$$

You wrote $9$.

With correct value, I got $$ [DNM] = \dfrac{98\sqrt{3}}{19}$$

Comment: In an olympiad, how much do you believe I would get for my work?

Comment: For numerical mistakes, they won't deduct too much. Maybe $-2$ or $-3$

Comment: out of 10 I assume correct?

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and I wish you all the best